# Azure Function to download blobs with OAuth token

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a huge set of PDFs that are stored on a blob container (let's call it demo_container) , within each pdf file there are links to other pdfs (links are redirecting to the blob also).

i'm looking for a way to make sure that links will work only if the user have the rights (configured through IAM) to access that blob ; the idea behind this is that even if somebody steal one pdf , he won't be able to open other ones.

this needs using OAuth in order to gets the token etc.. , ended up thinking that i need to create a function that would act as a redirector (typically , links in PDFs would call my API with the name of the desired file in the query) . First of all am i right so far ? or is there a way to do this in an easier way ?

In order to go as fast as possible (and since it shouldn't be something requiring too much programming) , i went with a powershell code , did the app registration of my app and gave it the access to the Storage_API (with user impersonation) and Graph_API just as stated in the MS docs.

when i call my API on my browser i get the MS authentication page and everything works fine , in my code i try to make sur that the token was passed correctly so i download a blob within the context of the function and check it size.
Thing is , it should work only if i log with an account that have the right to connect to this blob (IAM is configured on the Sto account and the container) , but i don't know why the script works the same no matter who is authenticated.
My code to test :

```
using namespace System.Net
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
$context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -name "hamzasto" -ResourceGroupName "testrg").context
$temp=Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "blob1" -Blob "sample.pdf" -Destination ".\" -context $context -force
$body="Size of the file is "+($temp.length)
# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
ContentType = 'text/html'
Body = $body
})
```

i'm very confused since this is quite weird that the function can access the blob (no SAS used anywhere in the function) with tokens from users that shouldn't be able to . all the help is welcome

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To put it simply,  you want users to download blobs by access tokens obtained from Azure AD? Are you developing a web app?

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to do , i've looked in all the documentation but i haven't found any other way except by using a web app.  Not being a dev my self, i tried using Azure Functions with PowerShell Core code as a way to code the least possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use an additional Azure function, you can do this on your web app directly if you get an access token with a scope: `https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation`

I write a simple demo for you, it uses `msal.js` to log in users and gets access token for storage blob, just refer to code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Azure AD test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.4.4/js/msal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
                    
        <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign in</button><br/>
        <div id="WelcomeMessage"/><br/>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var clientAppID = ""
    var tenantID = ""
    var storageAccount = ""
    
    var demoScops = {
         scopes:["https://"+ storageAccount +".blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation"]
    }

    var msalConfig = {
             auth: {
                 clientId: clientAppID,
                 authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID
            },
             cache: {
                 cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                 storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
    };
     

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
             
    
    function signIn() {
     
         myMSALObj.loginPopup(demoScops).then(function (loginResponse) {
            console.log(loginResponse);
            initPage();
             
         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
     }
     
    function initPage(){
        showWelcomeMessage();
     }
     

     
     function showWelcomeMessage() {
             
         var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
         divWelcome.innerHTML = 'welcome! ' + myMSALObj.account.userName + '<div> blobURL: <input id = "bloburl"/><button onClick="downloadBlob()">download blob</button><div id="errorMessage"/><div>';
         var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
         
         loginbutton.innerHTML = 'sign out';
         loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
     }
     
     function downloadBlob(){
         myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(demoScops).then(function (tokenResponse) {
            var blobURL = document.getElementById('bloburl').value;
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = '';
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.style = "display: none";
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = blobURL.split('/').pop();
                a.click();
            }else{
                console.log(xhttp.response)
                document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = 'error';
            }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", blobURL);
            xhttp.responseType = "blob";
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', '2017-11-09');
            xhttp.send(); 
              
              
         }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              })
        }     
     
   
 
     
     function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
     }
     
     function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
         if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
             return false;
         }
         return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
             errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
             errorCode === "login_required";
     }
     

     var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
     var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
     var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
     var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
     var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
     var isEdge = msedge > 0;

     var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";
     
     if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
          if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
              initPage()
          }
     }
     else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
         document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
              myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
         };
         if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
              initPage()
          }
     } else {
         console.error('Please set a valid login type');
     }
     
     

      function signOut() {
          window.localStorage.clear();
          myMSALObj.logout();
      }
    
</script>

</html>
```

Result:

I granted my first test account data reader role of my storage account container:
[image]

When I use this account to access blobs under this container, it works as excepted:
[image]

When I use another test account that has no read perrmison, the user is unable to access it:
[image]

Btw, before you run the logic on a html page, pls make sure you have enabled CORS for your storage account:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took to help , i'll try this as soon as i can (your solution seems very logic) , need to refresh my JS skills to understand the details of your script .  once again thanks for your time :)

Comment: Actually this won't solve my problem . the file links i'm working with are within Pdf File , this means that when a user clic on a link (within the pdf ) there must be something that will catch his request and send him back the file he is looking for (if he is authorized to acces it of course) , your solution (even if it solves the downloading problem) would add complexity to the end user. the authentication part is already working through the App Reg part (which worked fine and gave me a token) , i'm missing the part on sending back the blob via HTTP using the bearer token header